# Akka RestartSource retries forever despite maxRetries being < 5 and > 0

Tags: scala, akka

I am trying to find out why i get an endless loop here:

```
object TestCase {
  implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.global
  implicit val actorSystem: ActorSystem           = ActorSystem()
  implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContext = actorSystem.dispatcher

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val finiteSource = Source(1 to 5).mapAsync(2) {
      i =>
        if(i == 2) {
          Future {
            Thread.sleep(50)
            i
            throw new RuntimeException()
          }
        } else Future.successful(i)




    }
    val tt = Source(1 to 5).flatMapConcat { i  =>
      println("--------------------------->"+ i)
      finiteSource
    }
    val forever: Source[Int, NotUsed] = RestartSource.onFailuresWithBackoff(
      minBackoff = Duration(10, MILLISECONDS),
      maxBackoff= Duration(10, MILLISECONDS),
      randomFactor=  0.1,
      maxRestarts= 2)(() => tt)



    val tt1 = forever.runWith(Sink.foreach(println))



    println(Await.result(tt1, Duration.Inf ))
  }
}
```

if i run this, i get endless retries. but once i change the min+max backoff to a value bigger than the "request time" of 50ms, the max retry logic works.

did i find a bug? this behavior doesn't make sense to me. why would i need to know in advance how long my requests take to avoid endless loops?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs for `RestartSource.onFailuresWithBackoff`

> `maxRestarts`: the amount of restarts is capped to this amount within a time frame of `minBackoff`.  Passing 0 will cause no restarts and a negative number will not cap the amount of restarts

Akka Streams 2.6.10 introduces `RestartSettings` which allows setting a `maxRestartsWithin` duration.

See [this github issue proposing `RestartSettings`](https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/29550): once a source inside a `RestartSource` has run for `minBackoff`, it is effectively immortal, as the intention behind `RestartSource` was that it be used for sources that will fail quickly.